# Debug Delphi continua parando mesmo após retirada de breakpoint?

Tags: delphi, debug, breakpoints

Meu Delphi XE está meio doido, tem algumas Units que persistem em fazer as paradas mesmo após eu retirar o Breakpoint (F5) da linha, alguém passou por isso e conseguiu resolver, ja exclui as DCUs e recompilei e nada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que pode ter ocorrido é que sua IDE esta configurada para não mostrar os Breakpoints, então...

Pressione CTRL+ALT+B ou acesse o Menu View->Debug Window->Breakpoints

Dessa forma aparecera a lista de Breakpoints que estão configuradas. Aparecera inclusive as que estão desativadas.

Aparecera exatamente abaixo da `Event Log`.

Se por ventura não aparecer nenhum Breakpoints, recomendo desinstalar a IDE e instalar novamente.

Comment: Era isso mesmo, tinha breakpoints ocultos, não sei porque, mas tinha, exclui todos da lista e esta normal agora